# Reactive observable that captures onrendered state changes (in scalajs / js)

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs, scala.js, monix

I am working with a library (`ScalaJS` and `react` specifically) where I have an interesting situation that I assume is pretty routine for an experienced reactive-programmer. I have a `Component` with `State` and a callback `shouldComponentUpdate(State)`. The basic idea here is that certainly if the callback is triggered but the `State` has not changed from the last `render`, return`false`. Otherwise, perhaps return `true` if the `State` change matters.

I am using a library `monix`  but it seems identical to other reactive libraries so I would imagine this is a fairly context-independent question.

I would like to do something like: have some state that reflects the deltas of `State` since the last `render`. On each `render`, clear the buffer. Or, have a `renderedState` subject that reflects all rendered states as a sequence, a `receivedState` subject that reflects all received  `State` updates, and a `needsUpdate` subject that reflects whether the latest `receivedState` matches the latest `renderedState`. I am having trouble actually executing these ideas, though. Here is where I am stuck at:

Here is what I've done for other callbacks:

```
lazy val channel_componentWillUpdate = channel_create[ComponentWillUpdate[Props, State, ResponsiveLayoutContainerBackend, TopNode]]

def componentWillUpdate(cwupd: ComponentWillUpdate[Props, State, ResponsiveLayoutContainerBackend, TopNode]) =
  Callback {
    channel_componentWillUpdate.onNext(cwupd)
  }
```

So when then `componentWillUpdate` callback is triggered, the handler fires `onNext` on the `channel` (subject).

The `shouldComponentUpdate` is different though. It returns a value, so it needs to be structured differently. I am having trouble thinking of the right adjustment.

To summarize a bit:

- `react` has callbacks at different stages of the view lifecycle, like `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, etc.
- I am handling all but one stage the same way - the shape of the callback is `State -> Callback<Void>` so alls I have to do is use a `Subject` for each type of lifecycle event and submit its `onNext` when the callback is triggered.
- But one type of event has shape either `State -> Boolean` or `State -> Callback<Boolean>`.
- I feel like I should be able to model this with a subject representing the delta between the last state rendered/received.
- However, I don't know how this fits into the reactive style.